# How to use Java JSmooth to include images in executable file?

Tags: java, image, jar, exe, jsmooth

Im creating a runnable Jar file from Eclipse for a Java file.  The Java file has a combobox that changes the image depending on the selection.

Im creating an .exe file for windows using jSmooth.

The .exe runs fine and the images change as expected when the images are in the same file as the .exe file.

How can I "include" the images in the .exe file such that I could send the .exe file to someone without sending them a bunch of images too (using jSmooth).

I do not see a clear method for doing this in JSmooth

Comment: Why not included the images in Jar?

Comment: Our PhD professor said that was not possible?  That it still requires to be in a folder

Comment: *was not possible*?  What, to embedded images inside a Jar file and use `Class#getResource` to load them?  If it is not possible, then `JSmooth` is useless. I use `exe4j` and that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out.  Using netbeans you can create a label and select an icon in the properties section and this will include the image for you in the jar file.